# custom chain upgrage substrate to 0.9.29, report error in uniques: "generic arguments must come before the first constraint"

Tags: build

rustc --version
rustc 1.66.0-nightly (2019147c5 2022-09-19)

```
% cargo check                             
    Checking sp-core v6.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
   Compiling librocksdb-sys v0.6.1+6.28.2
   Compiling node-runtime v2.0.1 (/Users/li/Documents/GitHub/xx-chain/runtime)
    Checking sp-trie v6.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-keystore v0.12.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-allocator v4.1.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-rpc v6.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-state-machine v0.12.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-io v6.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-application-crypto v6.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-sandbox v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-tasks v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-sysinfo v6.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-executor-common v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-runtime v6.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-keystore v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-executor-wasmi v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-executor-wasmtime v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-version v5.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-inherents v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-api v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-staking v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-executor v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-finality-grandpa v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-session v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-offchain v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-transaction-pool v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-keyring v6.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-consensus-vrf v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking pallet-contracts-primitives v6.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking fp-consensus v2.0.0-dev (https://github.com/xx-chain/frontier.git?branch=dev/polkadot-v0.9.29#c4623288)
    Checking sp-mmr-primitives v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-authority-discovery v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-npos-elections v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking pallet-contracts-rpc-runtime-api v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking frame-system-rpc-runtime-api v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking frame-support v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-consensus v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-timestamp v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-block-builder v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-blockchain v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-consensus-slots v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-transaction-storage-proof v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-authorship v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-transaction-pool-api v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sp-consensus-babe v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking fp-dynamic-fee v1.0.0 (https://github.com/xx-chain/frontier.git?branch=dev/polkadot-v0.9.29#c4623288)
    Checking sc-client-api v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking pallet-contracts-rpc v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking pallet-mmr-rpc v3.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-consensus v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-block-builder v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-state-db v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-network-common v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-tracing v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-chain-spec v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-network v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-rpc-api v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-network-sync v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-rpc v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-informant v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-network-light v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-offchain v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-transaction-pool v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-network-gossip v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-consensus-slots v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-consensus-epochs v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-finality-grandpa v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-consensus-babe v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-consensus-babe-rpc v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking substrate-frame-rpc-system v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-authority-discovery v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-finality-grandpa-rpc v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-sync-state-rpc v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-basic-authorship v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking sc-consensus-uncles v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking frame-system v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking frame-benchmarking v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking fp-evm v3.0.0-dev (https://github.com/xx-chain/frontier.git?branch=dev/polkadot-v0.9.29#c4623288)
    Checking pallet-timestamp v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking pallet-balances v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking node-primitives v2.0.0 (/Users/li/Documents/GitHub/xx-chain/primitives)
    Checking pallet-treasury v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking pallet-uniques v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
    Checking pallet-user-privileges v4.0.0 (/Users/li/Documents/GitHub/xx-chain/pallets/user-privileges)
error: generic arguments must come before the first constraint
   --> /Users/li/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/7c4ac35/frame/uniques/src/lib.rs:113:4
    |
112 |             Success = Self::AccountId,
    |             ------------------------- constraint
113 |             Self::Origin,
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
114 |             Self::CollectionId,
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ generic arguments
    |
help: move the constraint after the generic arguments
    |
111 |         type CreateOrigin: EnsureOriginWithArg<Self::Origin, Self::CollectionId, Success = Self::AccountId>;
    |                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    Checking pallet-evm v6.0.0-dev (https://github.com/xx-chain/frontier.git?branch=dev/polkadot-v0.9.29#c4623288)
error: could not compile `pallet-uniques` due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to run custom build command for `node-runtime v2.0.1 (/Users/li/Documents/GitHub/xx-chain/runtime)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/li/Documents/GitHub/xx-chain/target/debug/build/node-runtime-2d7feed94b5a307b/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  Information that should be included in a bug report.
  Executing build command: "/Users/li/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2022-09-20-aarch64-apple-darwin/bin/cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=/Users/li/Documents/GitHub/xx-chain/target/debug/wbuild/node-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--profile" "release"
  Using rustc version: rustc 1.66.0-nightly (2019147c5 2022-09-19)


  --- stderr
     Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.46
     Compiling quote v1.0.21
     Compiling unicode-ident v1.0.4
     Compiling syn v1.0.101
     Compiling version_check v0.9.4
     Compiling serde_derive v1.0.145
     Compiling serde v1.0.145
     Compiling thiserror v1.0.37
     Compiling typenum v1.15.0
     Compiling once_cell v1.15.0
     Compiling generic-array v0.14.6
     Compiling bytes v1.2.1
     Compiling autocfg v1.1.0
     Compiling byteorder v1.4.3
     Compiling unicode-xid v0.2.4
     Compiling arrayvec v0.7.2
     Compiling byte-slice-cast v1.2.1
     Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
     Compiling crunchy v0.2.2
     Compiling rustc-hex v2.1.0
     Compiling static_assertions v1.1.0
     Compiling rlp v0.5.1
     Compiling num-traits v0.2.15
     Compiling fixed-hash v0.7.0
     Compiling memchr v2.5.0
     Compiling impl-rlp v0.3.0
     Compiling hex v0.4.3
     Compiling log v0.4.17
     Compiling serde_json v1.0.85
     Compiling uint v0.9.4
     Compiling aho-corasick v0.7.19
     Compiling itoa v1.0.3
     Compiling regex-syntax v0.6.27
     Compiling ryu v1.0.11
     Compiling lazy_static v1.4.0
     Compiling ahash v0.7.6
     Compiling libc v0.2.133
     Compiling sp-std v4.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling pin-project-lite v0.2.9
     Compiling hash-db v0.15.2
     Compiling ref-cast v1.0.9
     Compiling synstructure v0.12.6
     Compiling hashbrown v0.12.3
     Compiling regex v1.6.0
     Compiling parity-util-mem v0.11.0
     Compiling tracing-core v0.1.29
     Compiling tracing v0.1.36
     Compiling Inflector v0.11.4
     Compiling hash256-std-hasher v0.15.2
     Compiling environmental v1.1.3
     Compiling bitflags v1.3.2
     Compiling integer-sqrt v0.1.5
     Compiling subtle v2.4.1
     Compiling thiserror-impl v1.0.37
     Compiling impl-trait-for-tuples v0.2.2
     Compiling derive_more v0.99.17
     Compiling zeroize_derive v1.3.2
     Compiling zeroize v1.5.7
     Compiling sp-debug-derive v4.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling ref-cast-impl v1.0.9
     Compiling parity-util-mem-derive v0.1.0
     Compiling secrecy v0.8.0
     Compiling either v1.8.0
     Compiling paste v1.0.9
     Compiling block-buffer v0.10.3
     Compiling crypto-common v0.1.6
     Compiling cpufeatures v0.2.5
     Compiling digest v0.10.5
     Compiling blake2 v0.10.4
     Compiling keccak v0.1.2
     Compiling twox-hash v1.6.3
     Compiling sha3 v0.10.5
     Compiling sha2 v0.10.6
     Compiling sp-core-hashing v4.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling rand_core v0.6.4
     Compiling digest v0.9.0
     Compiling const-oid v0.7.1
     Compiling ff v0.11.1
     Compiling signature v1.4.0
     Compiling crypto-bigint v0.3.2
     Compiling sp-core-hashing-proc-macro v5.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling der v0.5.1
     Compiling crypto-mac v0.11.1
     Compiling group v0.11.0
     Compiling base16ct v0.1.1
     Compiling hmac v0.11.0
     Compiling frame-support-procedural-tools-derive v3.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling smallvec v1.9.0
     Compiling itertools v0.10.5
     Compiling sec1 v0.2.1
     Compiling rfc6979 v0.1.0
     Compiling cfg-expr v0.10.3
     Compiling tt-call v1.0.8
     Compiling elliptic-curve v0.11.12
     Compiling ecdsa v0.13.4
     Compiling k256 v0.10.4
     Compiling tiny-keccak v2.0.2
     Compiling proc-macro-error-attr v1.0.4
     Compiling proc-macro-error v1.0.4
     Compiling rlp-derive v0.1.0
     Compiling triehash v0.8.4
     Compiling enumflags2_derive v0.7.4
     Compiling rand_core v0.5.1
     Compiling jobserver v0.1.25
     Compiling num-integer v0.1.45
     Compiling generic-array v0.12.4
     Compiling toml v0.5.9
     Compiling enumflags2 v0.7.5
     Compiling cc v1.0.73
     Compiling futures-core v0.3.24
     Compiling proc-macro-crate v1.2.1
     Compiling zstd-safe v5.0.2+zstd.1.5.2
     Compiling frame-support-procedural-tools v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling zstd-sys v2.0.1+zstd.1.5.2
     Compiling ss58-registry v1.29.1
     Compiling futures-task v0.3.24
     Compiling auto_impl v0.5.0
     Compiling byte-tools v0.3.1
     Compiling parity-scale-codec-derive v3.1.3
     Compiling scale-info-derive v2.2.0
     Compiling sp-runtime-interface-proc-macro v5.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling sp-api-proc-macro v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling frame-support-procedural v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling rustversion v1.0.9
     Compiling parity-scale-codec v3.2.1
     Compiling block-padding v0.1.5
     Compiling sp-version-proc-macro v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling digest v0.8.1
     Compiling trie-db v0.24.0
     Compiling trie-root v0.17.0
     Compiling semver v1.0.14
     Compiling scale-info v2.2.0
     Compiling impl-codec v0.6.0
     Compiling sp-storage v6.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling sp-wasm-interface v6.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling sp-tracing v5.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling futures-sink v0.3.24
     Compiling camino v1.1.1
     Compiling arrayvec v0.4.12
     Compiling futures-channel v0.3.24
     Compiling futures-util v0.3.24
     Compiling sp-externalities v0.12.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling primitive-types v0.11.1
     Compiling sp-arithmetic v5.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling frame-metadata v15.0.0
     Compiling ethbloom v0.12.1
     Compiling block-buffer v0.7.3
     Compiling sp-runtime-interface v6.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling ethereum-types v0.13.1
     Compiling evm-core v0.35.0 (https://github.com/rust-blockchain/evm?rev=51b8c2ce3104265e1fd5bb0fe5cdfd2e0938239c#51b8c2ce)
     Compiling ethereum v0.12.0
     Compiling evm-runtime v0.35.0 (https://github.com/rust-blockchain/evm?rev=51b8c2ce3104265e1fd5bb0fe5cdfd2e0938239c#51b8c2ce)
     Compiling memory-db v0.29.0
     Compiling num-rational v0.2.4
     Compiling sp-core v6.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling num-bigint v0.4.3
     Compiling pin-utils v0.1.0
     Compiling semver-parser v0.7.0
     Compiling ppv-lite86 v0.2.16
     Compiling opaque-debug v0.2.3
     Compiling evm-gasometer v0.35.0 (https://github.com/rust-blockchain/evm?rev=51b8c2ce3104265e1fd5bb0fe5cdfd2e0938239c#51b8c2ce)
     Compiling sp-io v6.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling sp-inherents v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling sp-trie v6.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling nodrop v0.1.14
     Compiling evm v0.35.0 (https://github.com/rust-blockchain/evm?rev=51b8c2ce3104265e1fd5bb0fe5cdfd2e0938239c#51b8c2ce)
     Compiling fake-simd v0.1.2
     Compiling arrayref v0.3.6
     Compiling parity-wasm v0.42.2
     Compiling libm v0.2.5
     Compiling heck v0.4.0
     Compiling sp-application-crypto v6.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling sha2 v0.8.2
     Compiling strum_macros v0.24.3
     Compiling sp-runtime v6.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling rand_chacha v0.2.2
     Compiling semver v0.6.0
     Compiling curve25519-dalek v2.1.3
     Compiling cargo-platform v0.1.2
     Compiling merlin v2.0.1
     Compiling parity-wasm v0.32.0
     Compiling num-iter v0.1.43
     Compiling num-rational v0.4.1
     Compiling futures-io v0.3.24
     Compiling async-trait v0.1.57
     Compiling arrayvec v0.5.2
     Compiling rustc-demangle v0.1.21
     Compiling constant_time_eq v0.1.5
     Compiling remove_dir_all v0.5.3
     Compiling fastrand v1.8.0
     Compiling same-file v1.0.6
     Compiling schnorrkel v0.9.1
     Compiling walkdir v2.3.2
     Compiling tempfile v3.3.0
     Compiling blake2-rfc v0.2.18
     Compiling sp-version v5.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling sp-staking v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling sp-authorship v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling wasm-gc-api v0.1.11
     Compiling futures v0.3.24
     Compiling strum v0.24.1
     Compiling cargo_metadata v0.14.2
     Compiling build-helper v0.1.1
     Compiling wasmi-validation v0.4.1
     Compiling block-buffer v0.9.0
     Compiling filetime v0.2.17
     Compiling memory_units v0.3.0
     Compiling ansi_term v0.12.1
     Compiling sp-api v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling hex-literal v0.3.4
     Compiling opaque-debug v0.3.0
     Compiling downcast-rs v1.2.0
     Compiling spin v0.5.2
     Compiling sha2 v0.9.9
     Compiling wasmi v0.9.1
     Compiling frame-support v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling sp-timestamp v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling sp-session v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling finality-grandpa v0.16.0
     Compiling sp-consensus-slots v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling pallet-contracts-primitives v6.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling sp-consensus-vrf v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling sp-npos-elections v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling rand v0.7.3
     Compiling curve25519-dalek v3.2.0
     Compiling ed25519 v1.5.2
     Compiling rand v0.8.5
     Compiling num-complex v0.4.2
     Compiling cfg-if v0.1.10
     Compiling ckb-merkle-mountain-range v0.3.2
     Compiling ed25519-dalek v1.0.1
     Compiling num v0.4.0
     Compiling fp-dynamic-fee v1.0.0 (https://github.com/xx-chain/frontier.git?branch=dev/polkadot-v0.9.29#c4623288)
     Compiling substrate-bn v0.6.0
     Compiling sp-consensus-babe v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling sp-sandbox v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling sp-finality-grandpa v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling sp-authority-discovery v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling sp-mmr-primitives v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling fp-consensus v2.0.0-dev (https://github.com/xx-chain/frontier.git?branch=dev/polkadot-v0.9.29#c4623288)
     Compiling wasm-instrument v0.1.1
     Compiling fp-storage v2.0.0 (https://github.com/xx-chain/frontier.git?branch=dev/polkadot-v0.9.29#c4623288)
     Compiling ripemd v0.1.3
     Compiling curve25519-dalek v4.0.0-pre.1
     Compiling pallet-contracts-proc-macro v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling safe-mix v1.0.1
     Compiling pallet-contracts-rpc-runtime-api v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling frame-system-rpc-runtime-api v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling sp-transaction-pool v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling sp-block-builder v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling sp-offchain v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling frame-system v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling fp-evm v3.0.0-dev (https://github.com/xx-chain/frontier.git?branch=dev/polkadot-v0.9.29#c4623288)
     Compiling pallet-timestamp v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling pallet-balances v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling node-primitives v2.0.0 (/Users/li/Documents/GitHub/xx-chain/primitives)
     Compiling pallet-uniques v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
     Compiling pallet-treasury v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.29#7c4ac358)
  error: generic arguments must come before the first constraint
     --> /Users/li/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/7c4ac35/frame/uniques/src/lib.rs:113:4
      |
  112 |             Success = Self::AccountId,
      |             ------------------------- constraint
  113 |             Self::Origin,
      |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  114 |             Self::CollectionId,
      |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ generic arguments
      |
  help: move the constraint after the generic arguments
      |
  111 |         type CreateOrigin: EnsureOriginWithArg<Self::Origin, Self::CollectionId, Success = Self::AccountId>;
      |                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  error: could not compile `pallet-uniques` due to previous error
  warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

Answer (score 3):

We also did not really understood how it stopped compiling from one moment to the next moment. [Here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/commit/c24431eb6a95197550b30715a4c124be1aea79de) you find the commit that fixed this on master. So, the only solution is to update your Substrate deps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a commit on substrate which I think is related to the compiler version you are using:

```
commit c6ebc1e73f85deba349db0ea785ad53addb6f69f
Author: Bastian Köcher <git@kchr.de>
Date:   Tue Sep 27 11:37:45 2022 +0200

    Fix compilation on 1.66 nightly (#12363)
```

Currently you are using substrate commit `7c4ac358c29c9748c6e8ed4e05910504cd01a3b9` which does not include the fix above.

Run `cargo update` and rebuild should solve this